# Android theme will not update status bar color

Tags: android, xamarin, android-appcompat

I'm struggling to get Android to update my status bar color. I'm using `AppCompatActivity` in Xamarin.Android.

My `values/styles.xml` file is like so:

```
<!-- Main theme -->
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
</style>
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/WindowBackground</item>
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Primary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/Accent</item>
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/PrimaryText</item>
  <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/SecondaryText</item>
</style>
```

Inside of `values-v21/styles.xml`, I have the following:

```
<!-- Main theme -->
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/PrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

However, the status bar will not update. If I use this however, from `OnCreate()`, the color updates just fine:

```
protected virtual void SetupStatusBar()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        return;

    Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);

    Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

#pragma warning disable 618
    Window.SetStatusBarColor(Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.PrimaryDark));
#pragma warning restore 618
}
```

I'm a bit confused, because all I'm doing is copying the XML directives.

I'm using a Galaxy Tab S2 running Android 5.1.1, which is API 22, and should trigger the `v21` style override, I'd think.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. Your expectation of overriding the theme on your API 22 will not be fulfilled this way.

> I am assuming that in your manifest you have declared app theme as
>   `MainTheme`

in your values-v21. So your code would be like this

```
<!-- Main theme -->
<style name="MainTheme>" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/PrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Or in your way:

```
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/PrimaryDark</item>
</style>
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
</style>
```

So now android will reference styles from MainTheme and would replace the duplicate attributes if any, giving priority to values-21 xml.