# How to change font color of Android status bar?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-statusbar

I've been trying to change the font color of the status bar using Xamarin (where the Battery, Signal and Clock is)...

Can somebody advice me how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: This will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34859573/5167909

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what API level your trying to target, but if you can use API 23 specific stuff, you can add the following to your AppTheme styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

when android:windowLightStatusBar is set to true, status bar text color will be able to be seen when the status bar color is white, and vice-versa when android:windowLightStatusBar is set to false, status bar text color will be designed to be seen when the status bar color is dark.

Example:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- Status bar stuff. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item> 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt > Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.M)
{
        var activity = Activity; //your activity ref.. 
        var needWhite = true; //your goal

        // Fetch the current flags.
        var flags = activity.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
        // Update the SystemUiVisibility dependening on whether we want a Light or Dark theme.
        if (needWhite)
        {
            activity.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = flags | (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.LightNavigationBar;
        }
        else
        {
            activity.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = flags ^ (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.LightNavigationBar;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change it by changing "colorPrimaryDark" attiribute of "color.xml" file where under android native project.

Comment: This only changes the background color of the status bar. Not the font color